# Emeditor Multiple Marking

Tags: notepad++, emeditor, itemeditor

I have this text file containing employees and their details, I want to mark only those employees whose job_title is Operations Manager and their business_email. Please tell me how can I do this in Emeditor or Notepad++ or any other way?

Sample

```
["state": true,
    "employees": [
        {
            "first_name": "Kate",
            "last_name": "Garland",
            "headline": "Director of Communications and Enrollment",
            "job_title": "Director of Communications and Enrollment",
            "location": "Clearwater, Florida, United States",
            "business_email": "kgarland@11howard.com",
            "personal_email": "kate@kateyoga.com",, fi}{ln}"
        },
        {
            "first_name": "Dorina",
            "last_name": "Valentin",
            "headline": "Operations Manager",
            "job_title": "Operations Manager",
            "location": "New York, New York, United States",
            "business_email": "dvalentin@11howard.com",
            "personal_email": "",, fi}{ln}"
        },
        {
            "first_name": "Shannon",
            "last_name": "Sheppard",
            "headline": "Founding Member",
            "job_title": "Founding Member",
            "location": "Tampa, Florida, United States",
            "business_email": "ssheppard@11howard.com",
            "personal_email": "sheppardsm@hotmail.com",, fn}{ln}"
        },
        {
            "first_name": "Nicole",
            "last_name": "Peacock",
            "headline": "Realtor",
            "job_title": "Realtor",
            "location": "Dayton Metropolitan Area",
            "business_email": "npeacock@11howard.com",
            "personal_email": "nicoleschuder@hotmail.com",, fi}{ln}"
        },
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? How big is the file you are wanting to parse? It would be helpful if you included more details.

Comment: use a JSON parser. **avoid to publish real names and mails**

Comment: @MaximilianBallard original txt file size is 100mb, I tried to json decode this but the file is not properly parsed in json so i guess i need to use notepad++ or emeditor for marking the fields and then removing unmarked lines.

Comment: I can also attach sample data txt file, if you guys can help with it

Comment: @Toto these above are not real , just sample demo data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the following options under EmEditor - Find - Advanced button, and set the following options:

Search for:
^\s*{.+?"Operations Manager".+?},

and Click the "Select All" button.

[image]

Then Find ".", click "In the selection only" and Click the Bookmark button:

[image]

This will bookmark the relevant records. If you just want to bookmark the email (It wasn't entirely clear in your question), then change "." to "business_email" and click bookmark.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the JSON file is formatted correctly, you can Find (Ctrl-F) for the string `"job_title": "Operations Manager"`. In the Find dialog there is the button "Bookmark" if you want to mark those lines.

Comment: Its not properly formatted, if it was i would have directly converted to csv using pandas.
What you said i need their business email aswell. so how can i mark 2 fields?

Comment: A better Find string would be the regex `"job_title":\s*"Operations Manager"`. Make sure to select Regular Expressions. Unfortunately EmEditor cannot parse JSON as objects so it can't traverse the objects to find a specific field. But I'm not sure why you can't use pandas for this.

Answer (score 0):

**@Claudia**, your request is already done for you?
If not, let me know if one of my example fit your request.

I could not tell from your request,

- whether this is a recurring task. In this case I would always create a macro in EmEditor.
- 100mb size are a lot data sets, filtering the data would be more convenient from my point of view than just mark it only.

How familiar are you with EmEditor?
Whit EmEditor it is also very easy to extract or filter them (I don't know that Notepad++ has this function filter, extract, etc.. Since Notepad++ can not open my large files, I have no experience with Notepad++).
Here you can extract the searched data sets (the original file remains unchanged) and you have a new file with the hits.
Whether these are found with the filter or search/search replace does not really matter.
Please always use the latest version (also beta version) of EmEditor.

***first example** (Find - Extract):*

- if you use in point 4 "3", you get the hole data sets, with **0** you get only lines above

[find-extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4xqJ.png)

[find-extract-result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s97aZ.png)

***second example** (macro):*
In this marcro are only single command where can be done also manualy.
my Steps:

- stop refresh window
- search data sets with regular expressions and extract it to new doc with tabulator delimiter
- put the headline on top
- activate CSV view (with tab)
- activate heading line
- filter Operations Manager (it whould be also posible to extract hits directly)

  ```
   Redraw = false
   document.selection.Replace("{\\n\\s{1,}\"first_name\":(.+),\\n\\s{1,}\"\\w+\":\\s{1,}(.+),\\n\\s{1,}\"\\w+\":\\s{1,}(.+),\\n\\s{1,}\"\\w+\":\\s{1,}(.+),\\n\\s{1,}\"\\w+\":\\s{1,}(.+),\\n\\s{1,}\"\\w+\":\\s{1,}(.+),\\n\\s{1,}\"\\w+\":\\s{1,}(.+),,","\\1\\t\\2\\t\\3\\t\\4\\t\\5\\t\\6\\t\\7",eeReplaceAll | eeFindReplaceRegExp | eeFindExtract | eeFindLineOnly,0);
   document.selection.StartOfDocument(false);
   document.selection.LineOpen(true);
   document.selection.Text= "first_name\tlast_name\theadline\tjob_title\tlocation\tbusiness_email\tpersonal_email"
   editor.ExecuteCommandByID(22529);  // 
   document.HeadingLines = 1
   document.Filter("Operations Manager",4,0,0,0,0,0,0);
  ```

[result_macro_whitout_filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5pXM.png)

[result_macro_with_filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5jWc.png)

You can only really compare the speeds of the different solution options with the original data.